# How to solve the "Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected" on Heroku when pushing a Django project?

Tags: django, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I followed all the [steps indicated in the heroku site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) and each time I get the same error:

```
$ git push heroku master

Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 4.12 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)


 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:glacial-mountain-3911.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:glacial-mountain-3911.git'
```

I've looked for other solutions, some of them have a bit differences, but none of them have run :(

Here's the structure of my project:

```
drwxr-xr-x   9 marcpou  staff  306 28 jul 22:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  17 marcpou  staff  578 28 jul 00:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x  13 marcpou  staff  442 28 jul 22:09 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 marcpou  staff   24 28 jul 01:05 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 marcpou  staff   32 28 jul 00:57 Procfile
drwxr-xr-x  10 marcpou  staff  340 28 jul 00:58 hellodjango
-rw-r--r--   1 marcpou  staff  254 28 jul 00:56 manage.py
-rw-r--r--   1 marcpou  staff  154 28 jul 22:08 requeriments.txt
drwxr-xr-x   6 marcpou  staff  204 28 jul 00:56 venv
```

And the content of the requeriments.txt file

```
Django==1.5.1
distribute==0.6.34
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==17.5
psycopg2==2.5.1
static==0.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

And that's the content of the Procfile

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi
```

I see that the file "hellodjango.wsgi" don't exist on my project. What should be the content? These are the files of my project.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 marcpou  staff     0 28 jul 00:56 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 marcpou  staff   155 28 jul 00:57 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 marcpou  staff  5869 28 jul 01:02 settings.py
-rw-r--r--  1 marcpou  staff  2876 28 jul 00:58 settings.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 marcpou  staff   571 28 jul 00:56 urls.py
-rw-r--r--  1 marcpou  staff   293 28 jul 00:58 urls.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 marcpou  staff  1557 28 jul 01:04 wsgi.py
-rw-r--r--  1 marcpou  staff  1059 28 jul 00:57 wsgi.pyc
```

The test the Push process on heroku, I've created an application, but I haven't edited anything, that means that I haven't set any database connection.

Does anybody have any idea? I suppose that the error is trivial, but I'm unable to see the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Requirements is spelt incorrectly. Perhaps that matters? `hellodjango.wsgi` refers to `hellodjango/wsgi.py`.

Comment: Yes, it was a mispelling error. For other users, be careful to name the file requIrEments.txt instead of requErIments.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that correct the spelling of requirements.txt will fix this.  Then on to the next problem of adding the postgres  db and PROMOTING it.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql.

Comment: Heroku now has a full description for their django support:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

If you're using windows-os also see instructions here:
http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2012/08/20/problems-with-deploying-heroku-django-app-from-windows/